# Using $http with Bootstrap UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an app that uses AngularJS and Bootstrap. I am trying *desperately* to get my autocomplete example working. My example works successfully when my service returns an array. However, when I try to hit a REST API with the $http service, I can no longer get auto-complete results to work.

[My Plunker is Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1XfaVHOkQbRdzqBTRdNj?p=preview)

There are two things I need to adhere to based on the way this function is used elsewhere:

```
1. The $http call must happen in the service.
2. The controller must call myService.getOptions.
```

Can someone please tell me why my code won't work. I'm SO desperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your service return the results, because in your promise it will return entire response, but you need to only provide the results, so just add a mapper in your service.

```
this.getOptions = function(prefix) {
    return $http.get('http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/zipSearch?zip=60629').then(function(response){
        return response.data.results; //Return results
    });
};
```

and in your view make some changes to adjust to the data:-

```
typeahead="option as option.marketName for option in getOptions($viewValue)"
<h4><span bind-html-unsafe="match.model.marketname | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span></h4>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IZmRPL?p=preview)**

Or use a mapper in your service to return the expected data format while returning the data:-

```
  return $http.get('http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/zipSearch?zip=60629').then(function(response){
      return (response.data.results || []).map(function(itm){return {id:itm.id, name:itm.marketname}}); //map your data
  });
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/388cAu?p=preview)**